# SQL error or missing database (no such column: RollNo)

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite

I was writing a java code using eclipse ide and sqlite (as my database) and on executing the SQL query using the statements:

```
String query="select Name,Surname,Fees,RollNo,AdNo from student where class='"+1+"'";
PreparedStatement pst=c.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

I got the error:

> SQL error or missing database (no such column: RollNo)

where Name,Surname,Fees,RollNo,AdNo are the valid and exact names of the columns in the table student

But when I am passing this query(given below) using this same set of statements it is displaying the whole table correctly

```
String query="select * from student where class='"+1+"'";
PreparedStatement pst=c.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

What is the problem with the code do I need to rename my columns although I have tried names like Roll_No and Ad_No but it is showing the same error.

Comment: camelcasing SQL column names is generally bad practice. usually stick with just lowercase

Comment: I renamed it to lower case also but it is not working and one more problem that I am facing is when I physically rename the column names in my database and then execute the query by:"select * from student" it is showing the previous column names not the updated one